# How to Fetch data from SQLite according to Month from a Date Column

Tags: php, sqlite, inner-join

I am facing a simple problem. I have always worked with MS SQL and MySQL, this is my first time with SQLite. I want to fetch data from the following table where the month from the date column is equal to the one provided.

```
RecNo feesId memberId feesAmount feesReceipt feesDate   feesPaidTillMonth feesPaidTillYear 
----- ------ -------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------------- ---------------- 
   1      1       15      10.00 fsadfdsf    2013-08-10                11             2013 
   2      2        5     100.00 122314      2013-08-10                 3             2015 
   3      3       13     444.00 sda         2013-08-10                 1             2013 
   4      4        5      66.50 5564        2013-08-10                11             2013
```

I want to get all the rows 'WHERE month(feesDate) = 08'
I know the month function is not of SQLite but I want to do the similar thing here. I searched Google and I got this:

```
 strftime('%m',[memberFees].[feesDate])
```

but it does not do the stuff I want. The whole Query where I want this function is this:

```
 SELECT [memberList].[memberId],[memberList].[memberFName], [memberList].[memberLName], 
[memberFees].[feesAmount],[memberFees].[feesDate],[memberFees].[feesPaidTillMonth],[memberFees].[feesPaidTillMonth]
FROM [memberFees] INNER JOIN [memberList] on [memberfees].[memberId] = [memberList].[memberId]
WHERE
strftime('%m',[memberFees].[feesDate]) = 8 AND [memberList].[memberLevel] = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's [`strftime()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with the `%m` format returns the month with leading zeroes:

```
strftime('%m',[memberFees].[feesDate]) = '08'
```